Is there a simplification for $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\frac{M}{2}-1}\frac{(M-2j)!}{M!} \frac{d^{2j}}{dx^{2j}} f(x)$?
Is there a closed or simplified version of
$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\frac{M}{2}-1}\frac{(M-2j)!}{M!} \frac{d^{2j}}{dx^{2j}} f(x)$ ?
I am mainly looking for any hints or directions to read further about, if these kind of expressions are well known. I was working on another problem and encountered such an expression.

Try the simplest function $f(x) = e^x$ then you get a pure sum of factorials which I doubt you can sum (in simple/elementary terms).

Makes sense Winther, thanks!
